# Cannot delete non-space whitespace character in excel

Tags: regex, excel, whitespace, trim

When bringing in data into excel via whatever method (import, paste, ...) I sometimes get the following issue. At the beginning of the cell there is an extra space in front of the text. Now I know the usual procedures to handle this namely:

```
trim(cell number)
```

and if its not a space character

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(cell number,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)))
```

But this time both of these didn't work. I did try other substitute CHAR's.

AND the character at the beginning is just plain weird. When I go to the very beginning of the cell and try to delete it I must hit the delete key twice to remove one space! But when I go to the first character in the cell and instead hit backspace I only need to press it once.

What else can I do to eliminate this weird non-space whitespace character?

Comment: Did you get the CHAR codes from the string?

Comment: I tried. I used ROW() to bring up every ASCII character to 255 and then tested that weird character against each one. All came up false. When using @Gary's Student answer I get two codes for one the one character.

Comment: Yeah. My guess is that you have a CRLF there. Have you tried the `CLEAN` function?  Do you know VBA?

Answer (score 2):

If cell **A1** contains non-visible junk characters, you must *identify* them before you can *remove* them.

Pick some cell and enter:

```
=IFERROR(CODE(MID($A$1,ROWS($1:1),1)),"")
```

and copy down.  This will give you the *CHAR* code for each character in **A1**

Then you can use *SUBSTITUTE()* to remove the offender.

Comment: Right, I tried to identify it but couldn't find the code. By using your method (Thank You BTW) the first character is ASCII 63 which is ?. In the cell there is no visible ?.  Then there is a second character which is ASCII 32 which is a space. Two characters for one space.

Comment: Well it looks like the codes your method returns are ASCII codes. I looked up some of the code numbers on the ASCII table and they match but don't match on the unicode table.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume column A has text where some cells are good and some have text with the weird space like character at the front. So some cells we want to change and some we don't.

1) Create a one column table with one letter in each cell. I decided to go over to the right to column H for the table. So for example cell H1 has A, cell H2 has B and so on.

2) Get the length of the cell we want to edit. I've put this formula in cell B1.

```
=LEN(A1)
```

3) Test the cell for the first letter. This gives us which cell to change and which not. I've put this formula in cell C1.

```
=ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A1),$H$1:$H$26,1,0))
```

4) Change (or not depending on step 3) using RIGHT and the result from LEN.

```
=IF(B1,RIGHT(A1,B1-2),A1)
```

Notice that I have to subtract 2 spaces and not one? Like I said it was a strange character.

5) Repeat down the column.

Answer (score 0):

If the first legitimate character in your string will be in the set [A-Za-z0-9] then you could use this formula:

```
=MID(A1,MIN(SEARCH({"a";"b";"c";"d";"e";"f";"g";"h";"i";"j";"k";"l";"m";"n";"o";"p";"q";"r";"s";"t";"u";"v";"w";"x";"y";"z";0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A1&"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890")),99)
```

where 99 is longer than the longest string might be.  If there are other legitimate starting characters, then add them to both the array constant and the string at the end.

If you might need to remove trailing spaces (char(32)), you can enclose the above in a TRIM function.